# convert json array into string array with only the value of json properties in react

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

i'm trying to convert this json array

```
[
{empnum:"10",fullname:"john doe",dateofhire:"2000-01-01:12:00:00", lastupdate:"2021-02-02"},
{empnum:"20",fullname:"john smith",dateofhire:"1990-02-01:12:00:00", lastupdate:"2021-01-02"},
{empnum:"30",fullname:"john wayne",dateofhire:"2005-01-03:12:00:00", lastupdate:"2021-02-01"},
]
```

into this 2 string arrays

```
["empnum","fullname","dateofhire","lastupdate"]

[
["10","john doe","2000-01-01:12:00:00","2021-02-02"],
["20","john smith","1990-02-01:12:00:00","2021-01-02"],
["30","john wayne","2005-01-03:12:00:00","2021-02-01"],
]
```

one contains the json properties and the other the values

I'm struggling using map and Object.entries but I got always errors

result is the json array

```
  const x = result.map((rec)=>{
    var keys = rec.map((e)=>{
    return(e.keys)
  })
  var values = keys.join(",").split(",")
  return values
  })
```

any hint how can I get this?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To get the first one, you can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to return a list of `keys` representing the attributes found in the objects
- To get the second one, you need to use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) twice to iterate over each item in the array, and each time, return values of the defined `keys` in this item

```js
const data = [
  {empnum:"10",fullname:"john doe",dateofhire:"2000-01-01:12:00:00", lastupdate:"2021-02-02"},
  {empnum:"20",fullname:"john smith",dateofhire:"1990-02-01:12:00:00", lastupdate:"2021-01-02"},
  {empnum:"30",fullname:"john wayne",dateofhire:"2005-01-03:12:00:00", lastupdate:"2021-02-01"},
]

// get properties from objects
const props = data.reduce((acc,item) => 
  [...new Set([...acc, ...Object.keys(item)])]
, []);

// for each item, return array of values for the properties above
const records = data.map(item =>
  props.map(key => item[key])
);

console.log(props);
console.log(records);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      empnum: "10",
      fullname: "john doe",
      dateofhire: "2000-01-01:12:00:00",
      lastupdate: "2021-02-02"
    },
    {
      empnum: "20",
      fullname: "john smith",
      dateofhire: "1990-02-01:12:00:00",
      lastupdate: "2021-01-02"
    },
    {
      empnum: "30",
      fullname: "john wayne",
      dateofhire: "2005-01-03:12:00:00",
      lastupdate: "2021-02-01"
    }
  ];

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('keys =', Object.keys(data[0]));
    const values = data.map(item => Object.entries(item).map(entry => entry[1]));
    console.log('values = ', values)
  }, []);

  return <div>This is a template react</div>;
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And here is [the repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-u1jw3j).